# How can I add read/write access permission in Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

How can I add read/write access permission while enroll/register new user using fabric_client/fabric_ca_client or is it possible?. As we have ACL in Hyperledger Composer to allow read/write access, is there any ACL in Hyperledger Fabric?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no ACLs in Fabric 1.0.  In Fabric 1.1 there is a new feature called Attribute Based Access Control that can be used to implement ACLs in chaincode.  In the chaincode you can retrieve the attributes of the enrollment certificate and allow or disallow access based upon those attributes.  However there isn't a declarative mechanism such as an ACL.